# Simple Assignment Operator become Complicated in Python

Tags: python, operators, variable-assignment

I have declared four variables [a=1,b=2,c=3,d=0] in python and swapping them in one line code using ',' and '=' (Simple Assignment Operator).

I have got multiple Answers and got confused. please help me...

**Case 1:**

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
d=0
a=a,b=b,c
print "a = " + str(a)
print "b = " + str(b)
print "c = " + str(c)
print "d = " + str(d)
```

**Output of Case 1:**

```
a = 2
b = 3
c = 3
d = 0
```

**Case 2:**

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
d=0
b=a,b=b,c
print "a = " + str(a)
print "b = " + str(b)
print "c = " + str(c)
print "d = " + str(d)
```

**Output of Case 2:**

```
a = 2
b = 3
c = 3
d = 0
```

**Case 3:**

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
d=0
c=a,b=b,c
print "a = " + str(a)
print "b = " + str(b)
print "c = " + str(c)
print "d = " + str(d)
```

**Output of Case 3:**

```
a = 2
b = 3
c = (2,3)
d = 0
```

**Case 4:**

```
a=1
b=2
c=3
d=0
d=a,b=b,c
print "a = " + str(a)
print "b = " + str(b)
print "c = " + str(c)
print "d = " + str(d)
```

**Output of Case 4:**

```
a = 2
b = 3
c = 3
d = (2,3)
```

**Confusion is:**

In the case number 3 and 4 the output is correct (as i expected). but in the case number 1 and 2 the value of a is 2 and value of b is 3. I expect the value should be (2,3). So what's problem in my code?

*[My Python Version is 2.7]*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

tl;dr: multiple assignments (multiple `=` statements on one line) are evaluated from left-to-right, not from right-to-left (after evaluating the right-hand-side expression).

To complicate matters, you are using tuple assignment and 'normal' assignment in a heady mix.

Tuple assignment uses one assignment operator, so to swap two variables, use:

```
a, b = b, a
```

The right-hand side *must* evaluate to a tuple of the same number of elements as there are variables on the left-hand side. You do that, so that's fine.

Now, in your examples, you are not only unpacking tuples. When the left-hand side contains only *one* variable, the tuple is not unpacked, just simply assigned:

```
a, b = 1, 2
a = b, a
```

becomes `(2, 1)`.

The fun starts when you use *multiple* assignments on the same line. These are processed from left to right.

So, the following simple example:

```
a = b = c = 1
```

means that `a` becomes `1`, then `b`, then `c`.

Now we can understand each case:

1. `a=a,b=b,c`, where `a = 1`, `b = 2`, `c = 3`.

   This becomes: evaluate `b, c` -> `(2, 3)`, then assign that to `a` -> `a = (2, 3)`. Then assign it to `a, b`, so `a = 2`, `b = 3`. Result: `a = 2`, `b = 3`, `c = 3`.
2. `b=a,b=b,c`, where `a = 1`, `b = 2`, `c = 3`.

   Same as the case before, but now `b = (2, 3)` is set first, then `b = 3` again, same result as case 1.
3. `c=a,b=b,c`, where `a = 1`, `b = 2`, `c = 3`.

   Input on the right-hand side the same as cases 1. and 2., but now we first set `c = (2, 3)`. End result as expected, `a = 2`, `b = 3`, `c = (2, 3)`.
4. `d=a,b=b,c`, where `a = 1`, `b = 2`, `c = 3`.

   Same as case 3. but now we set `d` instead. No surprises.

What confused you here is that the assignments, after the right-hand side has been evaluated, are processed from left to right, *not* from right to left.

For cases like these, it's actually easiest to run your code (wrapped in a function), through the [`dis.dis()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dis.html#dis.dis) to disassemble the python bytecode:

```
>>> import dis
>>> def f(): a=a,b=b,c
... 
>>> dis.dis(f)
  1           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (b)
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (c)
              6 BUILD_TUPLE              2
              9 DUP_TOP             
             10 STORE_FAST               1 (a)
             13 UNPACK_SEQUENCE          2
             16 STORE_FAST               1 (a)
             19 STORE_FAST               0 (b)
             22 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             25 RETURN_VALUE
```

This is the first case; note how after the `BUILD_TUPLE` and the `DUP_TOP` opcode (the latter creates an extra copy on the stack to serve the extra assignment), the first thing that happens is the `STORE_FAST` operation on *`a`*, followed by a `UNPACK_SEQUENCE` (the tuple assignment opcode), to then store the results into `a` and `b`.