# Is assigning a,b = c,a the same as b,a = a,c?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is assigning

```
a,b = c,a
```

the same as

```
b,a = a,c
```

It seems to be the same for the simple case where `a`, `b`, and `c` are numbers.

Is there a case where this fails?

Comment: It's the same no matter what

Comment: You completely changed the question. You now included *attribute assignment on the same object*. Assignment takes place from left to right, and you have **two `a` references** in your left-hand-side (one with an attribute).

Comment: I've rolled back your edit, because you replaced `a, b = c, a` with `a, a.b = c, a`, which is *not the same thing by far*.

Comment: So a, a.b =c, a is different from a.b, a = a,c. Should I make a new question about this or could you explain it here? Thanks.

Comment: @Renegade: I've addressed the issue you are facing already; the important thing to remember here is that the right-hand side is evaluated *first*, and assignment takes place second, from left to right.

Comment: @Renegade: your 'real problem' would be a duplicate of [Python Assignment Operator Precedence - (a, b) = a\[b\] = {}, 5](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32127908), really.

Answer (score 5):

No, there is no case where this fails. The two statements are exactly equivalent, because `a` and `b` are *independent*.

That's because the right-hand side values are put on the stack *first* before assignment takes place (from left to right). Assigning to `a` before `b` makes no difference, because `a` and `b` are entirely different names, and assignment to either one first won't affect the other.

So the first statement:

```
a,b = c,a
```

is executed as (psuedo-bytecode<sup>*</sup>)

```
PUSH C ON STACK
PUSH A ON STACK
SWAP TOP TWO VALUES OF STACK
POP TOP OF STACK, STORE IN A
POP TOP OF STACK, STORE IN B
```

while the second

```
b,a = a,c
```

is executed as

```
PUSH A ON STACK
PUSH C ON STACK
SWAP TOP TWO VALUES OF STACK
POP TOP OF STACK, STORE IN B
POP TOP OF STACK, STORE IN A
```

It doesn't matter what type the values referenced by `a`, `b` or `c` are.

Things can get more confusing if you were to [chain assignments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13657704/simple-assignment-operator-become-complicated-in-python) and / or [mix in subscriptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32127908/python-assignment-operator-precedence-a-b-ab-5). In all those cases the names being assigned to are not independent, and people usually don't realise that all assignment takes place *after* the right-hand side expression has been executed and that assignment takes place from left to right after that.

---

<sup>*</sup> See [How does swapping of members in the python tuples (a,b)=(b,a) work internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21047524/how-does-swapping-of-members-in-the-python-tuples-a-b-b-a-work-internally) for actual bytecode examples.

Comment: @Renegade: read my answer carefully:  *the right-hand side values are put on the stack first before assignment takes place (from left to right).* So when you assign to `current, current.node` from left to right, what do you think `current.node` is by the time the first assignment to `current` has been executed?

Answer (score 1):

It's the same in all cases, no matter what you're working with. So long as statements are equivalent (like yours are), the result will be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Short Answer ----- "Yes"..
a,b = c,a means a=c and b=a ...
b,a = a,c means b=a and a=c